# Can't enable/disable multi-user.target or graphical.target on CentOS stream 9

Tags: systemd, systemctl

I was trying the command `systemctl enable multi-user.target` but I got the following:

```
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=,
Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template
units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.
 
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
• A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
  .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
• A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
  a requirement dependency on it.
• A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
  D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
• In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
  instance name specified.
```

the same thing happens with `systemctl enable graphical.target`

trying to use `systemctl disable` for both has no effect

NOTE: I can use `systemctl isolate` or `systemctl set-default` then reboot to switch to any of the boot targets. But I just wanted to know why `systemctl enable/disable` isn't working for `mult-user.target` and `graphical.target`.